# I added repository to my repositories block in build.gradle but did not act

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I imported [FlexibleRichTextView library](https://github.com/daquexian/FlexibleRichTextView) in a gradle project in eclipse and added all necessary jar files to the project for resolving errors, but one error is remained ([Sereenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXcYr.png)). This error is related to [CodeView-android library](https://github.com/kbiakov/CodeView-android). For resolving this error too, i added `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` in my root `build.gradle` at the end of repositories and added the dependency `compile 'com.github.kbiakov:CodeView-android:1.3.1'` in dependencies block([Screenshot of build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYVIX.png)), but the error has not been resolved yet. 
what should I do?

Comment: Eclipse hasn't been supported for Android development since 2015. You need to use Android Studio or IntelliJ.

Comment: (almost) nobody is using eclipse, it is not supported for couple of years already, and it will become worse in future. That's why you will likely be unable to get help. You will have to move to Android Studio soon or later.

Answer (score 0):

The gradle file might have been cached by the IDE. Try restarting the project or sync the gradle project to reflect the newly picked changes.